# Is the unit $m^2$ for area size ambiguous?

Tags: mass, terminology, soft-question, si-units, distance

In normal case, we use $m^2$ to represent the size of an area - the product of two distance whose corresponding quantities are perpendicular. But it can also be simply the square of one distance, such as in gravity $F=G\frac{Mm}{r^2}$, we may calculate $r^2=(1m)^2=1m^2$, but it doesn't correspond to any area.

So, when we say $1m\times1m=1m^2$, we may refer to

1. We product two perpendicular $1m$ and get the corresponding area size;
2. We product two $1m$ whose quantity are the same (the same value and the same direction) and get some nonsense $1m^2$;
3. Furthermore, it can be any two $1m$ with any direction, not necessarily perpendicular or with the same direction, and we can product them and get a legally expressed $1m^2$.

In the three cases, $1m^2$ refer to totally different things, but they are all $1m^2$. Why? Is there any ambiguity of area definition causing this?

Furthermore, I suppose there maybe another area definition: use $1m$ to represent the area size in a unit circle - that is, $1m$ for what we refer as $\pi m^2$ currently. And it seems there's no problem at all for this new system - no confliction with any axiom at all. So I am also considering if it means that the unit of area size doesn't have to be $m^2$.

Comment: If I tell you that the acceleration due to gravity near the surface of the Earth is $g=9.8$m/s$^2$, do you interpret the s$^2$ as an area in time? Should you? Do you have to?

Comment: A unit is simply a reference to an arbitrary physical scale. To the physicist units are, more or less, meaningless. Whether we are measuring the size of a stick numerically in multiples of meters, multiples of proton diameters or fractions of furlongs is completely irrelevant. The stick always has the same actual length. The only thing that changes is the numerical multiplier. What you seem to be really struggling with is the geometric definition of an area. That is more a question of mathematics (how to define the area of an arbitrary surface through integrals) than physics.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it seems to be more about ambiguity of notation than physics.

Answer (score 4):

You are confusing the unit with the physical quantity.

The unit with which you measure an area should be identified with the unit with which you use to add the squared distance components in Pythagorean theorem before taking the square root for the arc length calculation. It is simply the convenient choice, and unit systems ought to value convenience. (Their foremost requirement is to be precise, for the sake of engineering and science, and I am openly saying this as a theorist.)

Unit systems always must allow such ambiguity. If you want to guarantee that the manipulations make sense, you should be enforcing rules on the physical quantities level, not on the units level. There is no possiblity for unit systems to enforce that kind of rules that you want them to. And so trying to do it there is really ``barking up the wrong tree".

Your case (3) is actually a standard thing done, and the result is a sum of cases (1) and (2). The mathematics needed to keep track of, separate them, and exploit the usefulness of having them summed this way, is already found.

You can define a new area unit corresponding to your circular disc's area idea. The issue with that definition is that it will be cumbersome basically everywhere, and nobody will be using it.

There are unit systems whereby the convenient property of having area units be the square of length units does not happen, and it is incredibly cumbersome to work in terms of them. One example is in nautical navigation, where horizontal lengths are long (nautical miles) and vertical lengths are short (maybe metres). Then the area unit horizontally is square nautical miles and vertically is metre miles, and people would have abandoned such a unit system if area calculations were common in that usage. Another example is SI unit itself, where we measure time and space with different units. Einstein's Special Theory of Relativity tells us that there is a privileged *spacetime conversion factor* that should have been set to 1. Sadly, SI units came before we understood this.

Comment: Good answer +1. Vertical distances (water depth) in traditional nautical units are measured in “fathoms”. Now of course it is in meters in the rest of the world outside of the US

Comment: I suppose if the wave height exceeds my fathom, I'm definitely gonna drown. Guaranteed by maths.

Answer (score 0):

The force generated by a field originating from a point source (e.g., gravity or charge) is equally strong at all points equidistant from that source.  All points equidistant from a given point represent a sphere in space.  Thus, in the equation $F=G\frac{Mm}{r^2}$, the $r^2$ term implies the area of a sphere that is a distance $r$ from the point source.  Indeed, the equation for gravitational force can be manipulated into a form that gives $F=\frac{km_1m_2}{4\pi r^2}$, where the denominator is the area of a sphere a distance $r$ from the point that is generating the gravitational field.